# Adding custom font to project, programmatically add item to plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, uifont

I want to add some font to my project. I have directory in my project contains fonts. So i can access to my font by:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"res_name" ofType:@"res_type" inDirectory:@"res_directory"];
```

But how to add it to my project so i will be able to call it like this:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Font-Name" size:14.0]
```

I'm only interest how to do this **programmatically** I'm assume that I have to add it to my plist, but can i do this programmatically?

I understand o have to use a in plist:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>swellfont.ttf</string>
</array>
```

But i cannot do this in Xcode manually. I want to check what fonts i included in my project in resource directory and add them programmatically from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [UIAppFonts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW18) key in Info.plist.

---

You can take a look at the [Core Text Font Manager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_FontManager_Ref/Reference/reference.html) to see if registering fonts by URL make them loadable with `+[UIFont fontWithName:]`.

Comment: But this is NOT a programmatically solution. I also have to load it from plist, and how i should handle add font to my plist?

Comment: You can't modify your app, including the plist. Even if you could, I very much doubt it would help. It's likely that UIAppFonts is only read during app launch. I don't understand why you think you must only do this programmatically since you can only ship a static set of fonts with your app.

Comment: Simple - i have a fonts directory in my app. I can even don't know what kind or how many fonts i have there. Directory in include in my project of course. There IS a solution to do this: https://github.com/zynga/FontLabel but I want to know is there were changes in new iOS/SDK versions couse this is for iOS 4.x original.

Comment: How can both be true, that the fonts are included in your project but you don't know what kind(?) and how many there are?

Comment: Included as a file in my directory. Once again my question is: how can i use a custom font? This is not in plist but only a file as a resource (first code in my original question). In my app as a developer i don't have to know how many fonts i have in my resource. App should read them all and know how to use it!

Comment: I agree with Ken. On the contrary, as a developer you SHOULD know how many fonts you have in your resource. By adding them to the plist you're just telling your app it's okay to use them. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: The problem is how to add it to plist without clicking on plist in Xcode. I'm perfectly fine with add them there, but not with a human iteraction. I want it to add this by code.

Comment: Then the FontLabel class from Zynga is your best bet. This functionality hasn't been changed in the iOS sdk, nor do I believe it will ever be.

Comment: Ah, so you mean at build time, not run time? You can use a run-script build phase. It could read the fonts folder and modify the Info.plist. You can code it in Python, which has a `plistlib` module, or any other scripting language you like.